# Deriving Bound for f'(x).

Tags: analysis

I am working on Mathematical Analysis I written by Zorich and I am stuck on a problem:

Let f be twice differentiable on an interval $I$. Let $M_0 = \sup_{x \in I}|f(x)| > 0, M_1 = \sup_{x \in I} |f'(x)| > 0$ and $M_2 = \sup_{x \in I} |f''(x)| > 0$. Show that

a) if $I = [-a, a]$, then 
$$|f'(x)| \leq \frac{M_0}{a} + \frac{x ^ 2 + a ^ 2}{2a}M_2.$$

b)

i) $M_1 \leq 2 \sqrt{M_0 M_1}$ if the length of $I$ is not less than $2\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}$.

ii) $M_1 \leq \sqrt{2M_0 M_2}$ if $I = \mathbb{R}$.

c) the numbers $2$ and $\sqrt 2$ in part b) cannot be replaced by smaller numbers.

I have managed to solve a) and the first part of b). I have little idea how to show the second part of b) and c). Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try: square both sides of the inequality in b.ii) and integrate $f'(x)^2$ by parts on an interval $I_{\alpha} = [-\alpha, \alpha]$, with a view toward letting $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$:
$$
\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f'(x)^2 \; dx = 
f'(x) f(x)|_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} - \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f''(x) \; f(x) \; dx,
$$
so
$$
\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f'(x)^2 \; dx \leq 
\left| f'(x) f(x)|_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \right| + \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} | f''(x) \; f(x)| \; dx
\leq
\left| f'(x) f(x)|_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \right| + \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} M_{2} \; M_{0} \; dx.
$$

Comment: Haven't checked this thoroughly, though.

Comment: For c) ii), consider $f(x)=(-1)^n((x-2n)^2-1)$ on the interval $[2n-1,2n+1]$. Then $M_0=1$, $M_1=2$, $M_2=2$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But this exercise is in the chapter about differentiation and it has not got to integration yet. So I was wondering if there is any other method just using derivatives and Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b)ii), we must perform the analysis again for some intervals $[x-a,x), (x,x+a]$ and we recover a similar result as above.

$$f(x-a)=f(x)+f'(x)(-a)+\frac{f''(c_1)}{2}(a)^2$$

$$f(x+a)=f(x)+f'(x)(a)+\frac{f''(c_2)}{2}(a)^2$$

Subtracting the two Taylor theorem estimates we obtain that:

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x-a)}{2a}-\frac{f''(c_1)+f''(c_2)}{4a}a^2$$

and we have that by triangle inequality:
$$|f'(x)|\leq\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{M_2a}{2}$$

Since $$|f'(x)|\leq \delta(a) ~~\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$$

it must be true that since $|f'(x)|\leq M_1$ for all $a$ as well, we must have that

$$M_1\leq \inf_{a}\delta(a)$$

for if the opposite happens, then there will be some subset of the reals where the function violates the first inequality.

We compute the infimum as follows:

$$\delta(a)=\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{a}{2}M_2\geq \frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{a}{2}M_2\geq 2\sqrt{\frac{M_0M_2}{2}}=\sqrt{2M_0M_2}$$

and the proposition is proven. The infimum happens when $a=\sqrt{\frac{2M_0}{M_2}}$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I kinda knew that I had to apply (a) to it, but did not realize that I can actually extend to any interval of the form [x - a, x + a]. This makes so much sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait a second, I though the delta depends on x as well. How do you know that the maximum value of |f'(x)| cannot appear at some x large enough so  that delta is also large?

Comment: Ah I get it. Thank you! I have solved the problem with your idea but not exactly the same.

Comment: How did you formulate it?

Comment: I applied the same method in (a) to the interval [x - a, x + a] and derive that the bound for each |f'(x)| is \sqrt{2 M_0 M_2}.

Comment: Good job, I refined my derivation myself shortly after you posted the comment questioning it.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: edited accordingly, and welcome!